# Would an obligate carnivore eat bread/grain?

Tags: biology, food

Say I have a race of obligate carnivores (for simplicity, we'll say they're felinoid). They have carnivore dentition, and *must* eat meat as a major component of their diet, but they can also eat fruit and derive nutrition from it. They *enjoy* fruit (and vegetables), but for the complex flavor and tartness rather than for sweetness, which they cannot taste. (They react to fats much the way humans react to sugars. My theory is that they can break down simple sugars, but not carbohydrates, they need lots of protein, and there is something present in meat that they cannot get from other sources short of artificial supplements; possibly [taurine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurine).)

Now, obviously they aren't going to eat a *lot* of breads/grains, except maybe as a form of dieting, however there are all sorts of interesting culinary dishes that can't be made without grains ([Wellington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beef_Wellington), burritos, fried chicken and so forth); in particular, grains give a certain "crunch" that's hard to replicate with pure animal products. Assuming that they've been exposed to these by other means (as they probably wouldn't invent cultivation of grain on their own), would they be able to eat such dishes? Or is there another way to make such dishes using only "meat" products or something else that is easier on their digestion?

I'll assume, first, that they *want* to eat such dishes, and second, that they aren't *toxic*. (That is, they can eat citrus, onions, grapes, cocoa, etc. without being poisoned. Grains might not be wonderful for their digestion, however, but they're willing to put up with a little extra "bulk" moving through their systems for the sake of excellent gastronomy.)

Comment: All animals in the world can eat whatever they want, at least they can digest it.... A cow can digest meat but is not going to eat meat because it lacks the predatory instincts to kill other animals and lack specialized teeth to eat meat. In the same way a carnivore can digest most plant matter with some exceptions, but they are not going to do it because they lack specialized teeth and they don't like the taste. We humans fall in between as we can digest a lot of things and we do eat a lot of things we are not supposed to even though our biology is specialized for eating rooths and fruits.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, If it evolved on earth then it's most likely that it can digest most things that are also evolved on earth. Few exceptions being poisons. For example, if you wanted you could even eat wood and digest it, not every single protein, but a good chunk of them... We don't do it because we are not specialized for chewing that stuff.

Comment: @Kyu : please note that almost all plants are poisonous, it's just that animals which eat them evolved a resistance to them in an evolutionary arms race. The less of a herbivore an animal is, the more plants are poisonous.

Comment: @vsz one could argue the same is true for animals, they are all poisons except to those who adapted to their toxicity, which in turn would make cannibalism always the safest and reliable source of food and also the healtiest.

Comment: @Kyu : not really. Very very few animals are inherently poisonous, while most (or all) plants actively create chemicals which otherwise would not be necessary for their functioning. For example, all tree barks contain pesticides of some variety or other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

Still [using cats as an example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5753635/), there is no issue using sugar and starch in food such as bread for energy and as a source for sugars. Even if the beast is an obligate carnivore, its metabolism will still be based around sugars and it will almost certainly retain the ability to use **free** sugars from diet instead of having to generate them all internally. The benefits are simply too large and availability of carbohydrates in diet too universal.

Where being obligate carnivore does impact the diet in comparison to humans is that ability of cats to digest those carbohydrates is limited in quantity. If your diet generally contains relatively little carbohydrates, you do not need a high capacity to digest them. The surplus will simply get wasted. The excess would typically end up feeding bacteria, which may or may not cause issues.

So small and occasional starch or sugar rich treats would totally work for obligate carnivores. As long as the quantity is small enough, there will be no issues. And even if you indulge too much, the consequences should not be worse than for humans, they'll just happen sooner at lower quantity.

An obligate carnivore might have lost its ability to taste sweetness and actually prefer crunchy bread with lots of texture and dietary fiber to sweets.

Note that while individuals cannot adapt to having more carbohydrates in their diet than they can digest, the species can. If your obligate carnivores have a diet with excess carbohydrates over several generations, the individuals with higher ability to digest them will have an evolutionary advantage and the typical capacity to digest carbohydrates will trend up.

Comment: "And even if you indulge too much, the consequences should not be worse than for humans, they'll just happen sooner at lower quantity." This feels ripe for elaboration. I'm guessing we aren't talking about the stuff that Google finds, namely weight gain and diabetes, since (I believe) those require that the carbs are actually digested? (Although the linked article seems to suggest otherwise...)

Comment: @Matthew Actually, that is apparently not known for sure. It has been assumed that obesity and diabetes will happen, hence those articles, but on the other hand, as you say, undigested sugar should not cause either of those things. I think being vague was the right call. It is not known and your carnivores are not actually cats, right?

Comment: @Matthew Bit of clarity I can offer : eating carbohydrates will still cause spikes in digested sugar and obligate carnivores might (or might not) be more sensitive to those because they would have evolved to those spikes being rarer. Cats specifically might be exceptionally sensitive since they seem to have very low levels of relevant enzymes but it is also speculated they just use something else we do not know instead.

Comment: They aren't *Terran* cats. While I try to generalize my questions when feasible, in this case I *am* specifically interested in "felinoids" (SF/F examples abound...). BTW, interesting article! (Now that I've had a chance to read, or at least skim, through most of it.) It sounds like eating carbs might actually result in a protein craving, which is neat (and useful!) to know. That actually helps with a point I've struggled with, which is that breads are *tasty*, but my characters (sometimes) don't want to eat them anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Using cats as an analogue, since they meet the criteria of felid obligate carnivores, I'd say that they'd be capable of eating bread.

A quick google image search is all that is needed to confirm this.

[image]

Comment: I think that is actually an Ewok.

Comment: There's a very highly likelihood that the cat was posed, given the preponderance of cute cat pictures on the Internet. I wouldn't call that evidence. It is kind of cute, though.

Comment: @Halfthawed and given the human hands holding the arms

Comment: @Halfthawed When I searched for cat eating bread I found lots of images of different cats eating bread unassisted. I just chose the most visually interesting one for this post.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: https://i.redd.it/ffmu06ga10m41.png

Comment: When I rescued my 2nd cat from a house, the next day my loaf of sliced bread was entirely minus its crust. My bag of dry food says ground corn and wheat (and is cheap af; fillers). They've never eaten fruit. So, yes yes and no, ime.

Comment: Or, a slightly more detailed link: https://petcentral.chewy.com/nutrition-pet-diet-tips-can-cats-eat-bread/

Comment: Can it be that, in case of pets, eating bread has psychological or social causes? The pets see their owner eating something, and then they want to try it too because they feel bonded to the owner.

Comment: @vsz, I would definitely say there is something to the theory that cats want to eat what you're eating just because *you're eating it*. Mine certainly seem interested in eating grapes, onions, chocolate, tea, citrus and stuff that literally *wreaks* of capsaicin, all of which are toxic and/or supposed to be disliked.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that an obligate carnivore *must* eat meat (e.g. cats because they can't produce taurine), but that doesn't stop them from eating other foods, such as sugars and grains. Their sense of taste, their dentition, etc. are simply tuned by evolution to *prefer* foods they *need* to survive because those who don't would tend to die before passing on their bad genes.

However, once their nutrition needs are met, e.g. a housecat with a reliable food supply that doesn't require hunting, they may eat all sorts of things that aren't nutritious because they're interesting (e.g. bugs, string) or assist with digestion (e.g. grass, bones).

We humans put all sorts of weird stuff in pet food that they'd never eat in the wild, in some cases specifically because it *isn't* nutritious and we want to put them on a diet. Also, while many cats would prefer raw food if given the choice, others actually prefer canned or kibble, so it's not unreasonable for felinoids to have a more diverse diet than what biology dictates, and it may vary wildly by individual. There's just a floor to how much of it must be meat.

Note that some felines *are* allergic to grains, but only in parts of the world where grains simply aren't found. Felines that are around grains in the wild *will* eat them occasionally, even if only second hand in the digestive track of their prey, so allergies were long ago removed from their gene pool.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

Bread contains little nutritional for cats, except for the sugar within it. Sugar itself isn't great for cats, especially given that they didn't evolve to deal with consuming large quantities of it, unlike omnivores such as *Homo Sapiens*. They also can't really digest plants. This is because their digestive system is too small. An obligate carnivore, such as a cat, will have a very short digestive system (specifically small intestine) because of how easy it is to break down meat. By contrast, an obligate herbivore, (such as, say, a koala) will have an incredibly long small intestine and very specializes enzymes. We humans, by the way, fall in between the two extremes.

And bread is pretty delicious. Not only the taste, but the various textures of bread isn't something that you can replicate given only meat. The cats would certainly be capable of eating them. Would there be problems? Yes - cats weren't exactly designed to eat grain. Still, they're more than capable of developing a tolerance for it, and such a tolerance is pretty pervasive among species that live near wild grains. Even if it isn't, by using small and constant exposure, it's possible to build up a tolerance enough for eating bread.

Comment: Humans are not designed to eat meat, but our livers adapted over the millenia, now it still kills us.... But way slower. I believe the same would apply to all animals.

Comment: @Kyu No, that information is factually incorrect. Humans are designed to eat meat (our incisors, for instance, are solely there for meat). Meat also does not kill us, not even 'way slower'. Meat isn't poisonous to human.

Comment: Human teeth can't chew raw meat like they can chew raw plant matter.  Meat in per sé doesn't kill us but the way our digestive system and bacterial flora interact with substances found in meat like the protein carnitina or cholesterol result in the production of deadly toxins that can accumulate over time and damage our systems.  Inform yourself on the TMAO cycle of the human liver.

Comment: Some groups of Neanderthal (not all) had specifically developed livers to slow down to process and thrive better on carnivore diets, but throughout human history the remaining groups of Neanderthals where either completely vegetarian while others were all-eaters just like Homo sapiens, but archeologists suggest the stapple food for most groups of Sapiens where indeed starches such as roots and fruits or berries, obviously meat and other foods were present but they were not the staple food for classic African homo Sapiens.

Comment: The eating of meat started becoming more and more common when humans began spreading around the world and adopting a nomadic lifestyle, this is when they met other hominids and eventually started settling down, then the invention of agriculture took place which permitted humans the luxury of farming animals.

Comment: To understand the reason certain animals have certain teeth structures you can't limit yourself to common sense, evolution doesn't work on common sense. You have to go down the entire history of that specific creature, and if you watch the evolution of humans beings and go down to primates, mammals, synapsids and so on down to when we where still living in the oceans and had fins, then then you start to understand better the reason teeth are structured the way they are, and realize it's not always about the diet of the animal, but can be the other way around.

Comment: @Kyu No. Evolution works *entirely* through common sense. Things which are useful are kept and things which aren't useful aren't. Animals and creatures only have traits either because they're useful or they used to be useful. I also completely fail to understand what you mean by 'it's the other way around'. Are you suggesting that we don't have teeth to eat meat, we eat meat to have teeth?

Comment: Also, yes, over consumption of meat can kill you and if you eat too much fat, that can kill you as well. That doesn't mean meat is dangerous. There's a rule in medicine - the difference between a poison and a drug is dosage. Everything can kill you in sufficient quantities. Including plants.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107703/discussion-between-halfthawed-and-kyu).

Comment: BTW, kudos for "the various textures of bread isn't something that you can replicate given only meat". As far as I can tell, that is indeed the case, and why I asked the question.